# Chrome web application stuck on draft version

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I am making a Chrome Web Store application. My app was on version 1.5 and recently I updated it to version 1.6 and then to version 1.7

For some reason the Developer dashboard is telling me that the public version is 1.5 and the draft version is 1.7, and I don't know how to make my app 1.7.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

From the Dashboard item's Edit page, you press "Publish changes".

**And then.. You wait.** Do not cancel a publish in progress.

Chrome Web Store runs heuristics on your app to check it for malicious or dangerous code. Usually this takes up to an hour before your version goes public.

Sometimes an extension/app is flagged for manual review. Then it can take longer, but there's no way to tell how long.

As long as your Dashboard says "Publishing in progress", you just have to wait. If it is in this state for too long, you can try [contacting Web Store support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/).

Comment: For some reasons sometimes the Chrome web store revert the version of my extensions and (re)put them to draft I don't know why.